# Adding XML documentation for Razor components

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor, .net-6.0

Is there a way of adding XML documentation for Razor components? I've noticed that some of Microsoft's components have documentation that shows up in IntelliSense:

[image]

However, adding the usual XML documentation to the code-behind partial class doesn't seem to work:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is my component.
/// </summary>
public partial class MyComponent : ComponentBase
{
    // ...
}
```

Is there another way of achieving this, or is it unsupported?

Comment: @lonix: The linked question asks about adding documentation to .razor files. My questions asks about code-behind files.

Answer (score 4):

> adding the usual XML documentation to the code-behind partial class doesn't seem to work

It works for me. But when I did a little test just now I noticed that there is a sort of delay at work here.

Adding a `///summary` and doing a Rebuild did, at first, nothing. But after making a small actual change to the Component the text did show up in Intellisense.

I'm not entirely sure how this refresh works but just hang on, it will show up eventually.

Comment: Thanks @Henk. I've tested your suggestion, and found that the comments I wrote on my components do show up _in the code-behind_ of the pages I use them from, but not in the pages' Razor editor itself. However, this might be an issue with the Razor/HTML editor in Visual Studio then.

Comment: I can see them in Razor code as well.

Comment: It's June 15th, 2022, just updated to VS 17.2.4. Doesn't show up for me in Razor for me. Also, I'd like there to be a way to put it in the Razor part of a component without a code-behind file. Sometimes I've got only a couple lines of code and don't want to bother with a code-behind.